# Decimal from Integer and Invalid Operands *Updated

Tags: c++, integer, decimal, operands

I am a beginner in C++ and for an assignment I wrote code for a number to English conversion.
My problem is getting the decimal from an integer. Upon advice I changed the void expand to a double value and changed the code for getting the decimal, and now I receive an "invalid operands of types double and int to binary operator %" for the remainder of my code.
Something to do with (value)?

```
void expand(double);

int main()

{
 ......
}
void expand(double value)
{
string const ones[20] = 
    { 
     " ...... "
    }           
if(value>1)
    {
    double decimalPart = value - (int)value;
    }
else if(value>=1000)
{
    expand(value/1000);
    cout<<" thousand";
    if(value % 1000)
.....
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: You can cut your code sample down to just relevant methods. There's an awful lot there, and things like your tens array aren't relevant to the solution, so it's a pain to have to filter through that.

Comment: double(3.75) - int(3.75) = 0.75

Comment: @McAdam331: No, it's not "just a suggestion", actually: it's a requirement. We expect minimal examples on Stack Overflow!

Comment: Why are you using floating-point types for currency values? Simply do not do that.

Comment: @lightnessracesinorbit fair enough! I was reviewing posts and got this one, and felt I should make that known. I figured 'suggestion' would help me to not sound rude haha.

Comment: @McAdam331: It does. And I don't blame you. Still, I think it's important to point out that this is a required step not an optional extra.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: First time on the forums and corrected the posting of irrelevant code. Thanks.

Comment: @JUTG: FYI this is not a forum it is a Q&A repository! More like a FAQ. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
void expand(int value)
```

Change the above to double for anything to work

```
void expand(double value)
```

Also you can get the decimal part alone by the following after changing the above

```
double decimalPart = value - (int)value;
```

Comment: I changed the datatypes and now the remainder of my code is giving me "invalid operands of types double and int to binary operator %".

Answer (score 0):

`value` is an `int` so any arithmetic operation done using it will disregard the decimal part. So what you are doing when passing `num` into the expand function is casting it as an `int`. Hence you are removing the decimals.

```c
double foo = 123.45;
expand(foo); // This will take only 123 and disregard the .45
```

Declare it as a double in `void expand(double value)` and see what happens.